# If I have a vector v, results of Av, Bv and A + B (where A and B are matrices), how can I find either A or B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I am given a $6$ x $1$ vector $v$, and the results of $Av$, $Bv$ and $A + B$ (here $A$ and $B$ are $6$ x $6$ matrices).

How can I find the value of matrix $A$ or $B$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You are give 6+6+6+36=54 numbers but you want to find 36+36=72 numbers. I don't think this is possible in general.

Comment: Consider the case where $v=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Thus you are given $A+B$ and the leftmost columns of $A$ and $B$. Clearly this isn't adequate to determine the other columns of $A$ or $B$.